# Webpack 2 Vendor Bundle

Tags: webpack

Ive created a `vendor/index.js` file in which i import e.g. React.
This file is my "vendor" entry point.

The result is a nice `vendor.js` with the stuff i expected. 
My Problem is that i have the same modules in my `main.js` bundle.

So i have the vendor stuff twice, once in `vendor.js` and once in `main.js`.

How can i prevent that?

```
  entry: {
    main: path.join(__dirname, "browser.jsx"),
    vendor: path.join(__dirname, "vendor", "index.js")
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) to put everything in the vendor bundle that is shared. Every module that references a shared module will refer to the `vendor` bundle, so it needs to be included before the actual bundle.

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor'
  })
]
```

This exact use case is described in more details in [Guides: Code Splitting - Libraries](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/) .

Comment: `webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin` has been removed (as of v4.x)